# Connection Timeout at "./rebar get-deps" / compiling EJabberd

Tags: ejabberd, rebar

I am trying to compile eJabberd on CentOS6. I am following the steps mentioned @ [https://www.process-one.net/docs/ejabberd/guide_en.html#htoc12][1]

However, this aborts with connection-timeout error while executing "make". 
Following is the error snipet from command prompt:

*

```
[root@CentOS-6-64-EN ejabberd-15.04]# make
rm -rf deps/.got
rm -rf deps/.built
/usr/lib64/erlang/bin/escript rebar get-deps && :> deps/.got
==> rel (get-deps)
==> ejabberd-15.04 (get-deps)
Pulling p1_cache_tab from {git,"git://github.com/processone/cache_tab",
                               "cca096330ce39e8b56fe0e0c478df1ff452e7751"}
github.com[0: 192.30.252.131]: errno=Connection timed out
fatal: unable to connect a socket (Connection timed out)
Initialized empty Git repository in /root/Desktop/eJabberd/ejabberd-15.04/deps/p1_cache_tab/.git/
ERROR: git clone -n git://github.com/processone/cache_tab p1_cache_tab failed with error: 128 and output:
github.com[0: 192.30.252.131]: errno=Connection timed out
fatal: unable to connect a socket (Connection timed out)
Initialized empty Git repository in /root/Desktop/eJabberd/ejabberd-15.04/deps/p1_cache_tab/.git/
ERROR: 'get-deps' failed while processing /root/Desktop/eJabberd/ejabberd-15.04: rebar_abort
make: *** [deps/.got] Error 1
```

*

On trying the command "./rebar get-deps", I get the same connection timeout error.
My network connectivity is fine and it seems the github link is broken. Please Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try replacing the dependancy link to Github using https:// instead of git://

It should fix your issue.
We will check the project to make sure all our dependancies use https url scheme instead of ssh.